# Can I connect all nodes in one subgraph to all nodes in another with a single DOT statement?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Consider this simple DOT file.

```
graph Foo
{
    subgraph foo
    {
        a; b; c;
    }

    subgraph bar
    {
        w; x; y;
    }

    {a,b,c} -- {w,x,y};
}
```

The statement `{a,b,c} -- {w,x,y}` means "connect all nodes in foo to all nodes in bar"...

...except that it doesn't. If I add a node to either `foo` or `bar` I have to change the statement which conncets them. I'd rather write `foo -- bar` but this doesn't work as I'd hope.

Is there any such command in DOT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the answer: **No**, there is no syntax for such a thing as connecting all nodes of a subgraph to all nodes of an other subgraph by only naming the subgraphs.

You will have to list *explicitely* all nodes to connect with each other.

---

And here is some nitpicking:

> The statement `{a,b,c} -- {w,x,y}` means "connect all nodes in foo to all nodes in bar"...

First, I don't think separating the nodes with a comma is correct (check the error output when generating the graph). Usually nodes are separated by a semicolon.

Second, the statement `{a; b; c; } -- {w; x; y; }` does **not** mean *connect all nodes in foo to all nodes in bar*, it means *connect the nodes a, b and c with the nodes w, x and y*. Adding an other node to either `foo` or `bar` should not generate any edges, this is *expected* behaviour.